# Check condition in date interval between now and next month

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in `PostgreSQL 10`. The table has the following structure

```
| date | entity | col1 | col2 |
|------+--------+------+------|
```

Every row represents  an event that happens to an entity in a given date. The event has attributes represented by `col1` and `col2`.

I want to add a new column that indicates if with respect to the current row  there are events in which the column `col2` fulfills a given condition (in the following example the condition is `col2 > 20`) in a given interval (say `1 month`) .

```
| date | entity | col1 | col2 | fulfill |
|------+--------+------+------+---------|
| t1   |   A    |  a1  |  10  |   F     |
| t1   |   B    |  b   |   9  |   F     |
| t2   |   A    |  a2  |  10  |   T     |
| t3   |   A    |  a3  |  25  |   F     |
| t3   |   B    |  b2  |   8  |   F     |
```

`t3`  is a date inside `t2 + interval 1 month`.

What is the most efficient way to acomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I got your problem correctly. My case is 'T if there is a value >= 10 between now an the next month'

I have the following data:

```
val  event_date  
---  ----------  
22   2016-12-31  -- should be T because val >= 10
8    2017-03-20  -- should be F because in [event_date, eventdate + 1 month no val >= 10]
6    2017-03-22  -- F
42   2017-12-31  -- T because there are 2 values >= 10 in next month
25   2018-01-24  -- T val >= 10
9    2018-02-11  -- F
1    2018-03-01  -- T because in month there is 1 val >= 10
2    2018-03-10  -- T same
20   2018-04-01  -- T
7    2018-04-01  -- T because an same day val >= 10
1    2018-07-24  -- F
22   2019-01-01  -- T
4    2020-10-22  -- T
123  2020-11-04  -- T
```

The query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    e1.val,
    e1.event_date,
    CASE
        WHEN MAX(e2.val) over (partition BY e1.event_date) >= 10
        THEN 'T'
        ELSE 'F'
    END AS fulfilled
FROM
    testdata.events e1
JOIN
    testdata.events e2
ON
    e1.event_date <= e2.event_date
AND e2.event_date <=(e1.event_date + interval '1 month') ::DATE
ORDER BY
    e1.event_date
```

The result:

```
val  event_date  fulfilled  
---  ----------  ---------  
22   2016-12-31  T          
8    2017-03-20  F          
6    2017-03-22  F          
42   2017-12-31  T          
25   2018-01-24  T          
9    2018-02-11  F          
1    2018-03-01  T          
2    2018-03-10  T          
20   2018-04-01  T          
7    2018-04-01  T          
1    2018-07-24  F          
22   2019-01-01  T          
4    2020-10-22  T          
123  2020-11-04  T
```

Currently I am not finding a solution without joining the same table which seems not very stylish to me.